# Swift private module access level

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I want to privately publish a repository. This is the company's iOS Security area. How can I publish to CocoaPods or SPM and consume without other areas seeing the content? Publish and consume without giving access to module content. Suggestions?

I published on CocoaPods and SPM privately. How can someone consume without accessing the content?

Comment: If you're using SPM just publish the module on a private git server.

Comment: What is the "content" in this context?